# Swift: How do you use a variable in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using a pod called iOSDropDown to display a dropdown selection menu for a textfield. I am getting a list of data from php to populate that selection menu that Im storing in a variable.

The PHP data passed stored in a swift variable looks like this when printed -> **"option01","option02","option03"**... and so on. This is dynamic data that will change that is why I am retrieving from PHP/MYSQL Database instead of just manually typing in the options in the Swift array.

Below is my code. What I am trying to do is use the "dropdownData" variable that holds the options for the array. Each option should be in its own row and separately selectable. What I am getting is one option, one string of coding with all my options as shown in the picture below.How would I use the dropdownData variable to display options instead of one string, one option?

dropdownData = "option01","option02","option03"... etc. ALL OPTIONS STORED IN THIS ONE ARRAY

```
let dropdownData : String = (dumpsArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "dropdownData") as! String
```

.

```
cell.nameField.optionArray = [dropdownData]
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdGDW.png)

In the image above there should be no comma after styrofoam cooler... the next product should be the next option displaying under the styrofoam cooler and separately selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `dumpsArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "dropdownData")` returns a String where names are comma separated,

so

```
    if let nameString = dumpsArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "dropdownData") as? String {
        let namesArray = nameString.components(separatedBy: ",")
        cell.nameField.optionArray = namesArray
    }
```

That should do

Comment: That works! Thank you been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: @btr199234: Am glad I could help :)